# How to add new references to a yaml-loaded dict?

Tags: ruamel.yaml

I'm loading a yaml dictionary and would like to use some of the existing anchors to extend the dictionary before writing it out again. Is this possible?

Example, let's say I have a yaml file:

```
a: &a 1
b: &b 2
```

With ruamel, how would I add a new value c that refereces a. In other words, how do I write:

```
a: &a 1
b: &b 2
c: *a
```

Comment: It is probably possible. At least provide where you start from and what you want to end up with by editing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anchored scalar `1` is loaded in ruamel.yaml as a `ScalarInt` and not as an integer, as on the
integer there would be no place to attach the actual anchor name, and more importantly because dumping
the same integer will not result in an anchored scalar and aliases. However when the same `ScalarInt` instance
is dumped you'll get an anchor for the first and aliases for all other occurences.

(`ScalarInt` will behave like normal integers for all common purposes, if you just need to use the loaded data.)

To get the output you want, you need to have the value that is associated with key `c` to be the same
as the value for `a`. You can just do that simply by assigning:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
a: &a 1
b: &b 2
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
data['c'] = data['a']
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
a: &a 1
b: &b 2
c: *a
```

If you want to start from Python code instead of loading some YAML with anchors,
you'll need to create the `ScalarInt`s yourself:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
a_val = ruamel.yaml.scalarint.ScalarInt(1, anchor='a')
data = dict(a=a_val, b=ruamel.yaml.scalarint.ScalarInt(2, anchor='b'), c=a_val)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

this also gives:

```
a: &a 1
b: &b 2
c: *a
```

Comment: Wow this is very magical (in the good It Just Works way). Would this be something worth documenting in the ruamel docs? At my company we use the references/aliases feature of yaml a lot and it was unclear from the ruamel docs what we could do with them beyond preserving them in round trips.

FWIW, I'd be happy to contribute to these docs if you'd like the help!

Comment: Follow-up question, in the original use case anchor `a` happened to be set on the value of `a`. If this wasn't the case, would there be an easy way to go from an anchor name to its value?

Comment: The anchor name is associated with the value 1 and is completely independent of that, That the key to that value happens to be the same scalar is even less relevant. After loading you can recurisvely walk over the loaded `data` and check each scalar and if finding the scalar value with the appropriate anchor do something with they key. In case of reloading the output, you'll find both `a` and `c` as key when searching for a value with anchor `a`.

Comment: If you can round-trip it, you can build it from scratch. As you noted there often is little documentation, but there are a lot of answered questions on SO. And as you noticed once I get a clear enough question, the answers tend to be useful. As I mentioned in many other answers, try to round-trip and when that works, do e.g. `print(data['a'], type(data['a']))` to get info on what is being built as intermediary.

Comment: That was indeed roughly the process I pursued before asking the question. Creating a yaml structure with anchors, loading it, and looking at types and the source, but there is also no documentation on these types so it's difficult to be sure of what the intended behavior is or what's implemented. For example, I did see that there was an `anchor` and `anchor_yaml` property but it was unclear if I should use those directly, or if they were just annotations that were strictly used for preservation of anchors on write, etc.

Comment: There's probably too many methods and types to be worth going back and adding documentation for, but I think simple pages that describe a high level overview of features (such as references and aliases) would go a long way. Having to ask questions on Stack makes features a lot more inaccessible I think.

Comment: Things are partly not documented, because I am not (sure) yet they are stable. E.g. comments need an overhaul and with a documented API I would feel more need to spent time on preserving/providing backward compatibly. So I usually don't provide documentation for things after implementing them. But I should review some stuff that has proven to be stable.